# how to Emphasize certain words in Text to Speech conversion using python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, pyttsx3, watson-text-to-speech

Hey I'm looking to emphasize certain words/phrases in a **Text to Speech conversion project**, But I couldn't find any open source library or API to do that.

Can anyone suggest me any open source libraries or any other way to solve this issue.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSML for "text to speech" messages. With the tag emphasis you emphasize a part of the text. This is an example for the azure text to speech service. Google SSML has the same tag

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="string">
  <voice  name="en-CA-HeatherRUS">
I will say this only once, <emphasis  level="strong">
I don't accept this anymore
</emphasis>
</voice>
</speak>
```

Comment: Thank's for the reply , But I'm looking for an opensource library that supports SSML. Do you know any.